# Pip install for warrant fails

Tags: python

I tried installing warrant using pip and got the following error:

```
Command "c:\...\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-lahy2d9f\\pycryptodome\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-record-2t9higml\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\\...\venv\include\site\python3.6\pycryptodome" 
failed with error code 1 in C:\\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-lahy2d9f\pycryptodome\
```

Has anyone else faced this issue before?

python version: 3.6

pip version: 19.0.1

Comment: What's the command you ran and full error? The formatting on the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: I just used pip install warrant

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I ran `pip3 install warrant`. I fixed the issue by installing a C compiler. Try installing Visual Studio build tools which provides a bunch of compilers.

[Link to Visual Studio build tools download](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools)